# Listing incoming branches in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, pull

I happen to work against a server repo which has a lot of named branches. I usually pull only the branch I'm currently working on, to keep me local repositories less cluttered.

Sometimes, I want to find out what branches in the server repo have any new changesets I can pull.

Is there any way I can list either the branch names, or the branch heads? Something like the opposite of:

```
$ hg log -r "outgoing() and head()"
```

Sure, I can do something along the lines of:

```
$ hg incoming | grep branch | uniq
```

but I'd be happy to find a more Mercurial-native and cross platform solution (I work on Windows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the time being, I decided to stick with the `grep` way. I added this to my `hgrc`:

```
[alias]
remote = !hg incoming | grep branch | sort | uniq
```

On Windows, I use `grep` and `uniq` found in [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/).

The sample output looks like this:

```
D:\Projects\MyProject>hg remote
branch:      1.4-stable
branch:      next-major
branch:      ticket-199
branch:      ticket-90
```

Unfortunately, this command still lists all the changesets under the hood, so running it can take some time.